# Python User Defined Function

Tags: python, pandas

I am working my way through an exercise using pandas. The Pandas data frame has a few columns,  named as  What_Type, Spend, Profit and corresponding values on the rows

A user defined function has been written to interrogate the first column "what_type" and return a value based on the value in the data frame. I believe the code is saying, if any of the values, hotels, fishing, Soccer are in the what_type column then apply some formula such as 1.5 * 10.

My question is in regards to code and how this function would be called to return a value.

(please see example below)

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['hotels', 10],['fishing', 20],['soccer', 15]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['what_type', 'spend'])

def what_type(x):
    if ['what_type'] in ['hotels', 'fishing', 'soccer']:
        what_type = 1.5 * 10
    else:
     what_type = 2.1 * 5
    return what_type
```

If I wanted to return the what_type value to my screen for the value 'hotel' (1.5 * 10) = 15, would I use the code below to return that value?

```
df.apply(what_type, axis = 1)

The result i get is this....

0    10.5
1    10.5
2    10.5
dtype: float64

I was expecting to get the output value 15.
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Avoid stuff like "I'm a noob" and "go easy". Instead, just make your best effort to ask a good question according to site rules. We'll know you're new by the content anyway, because we've all been there and still remember. Remember, this site is for people that are stuck or made a mistake. The only way you can screw up is not doing your due diligence when asking.

Comment: All that being said, please read (and follow) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. At the moment, I don't see an actual question in your post.

Comment: ok, thanks for the response. My question is -  If I wanted to print the def what_type return value to my screen would I use the code here?                    x.apply(self, what_type, axis = 1)

Comment: Please edit your question with a minimal reproducible example. The link I sent you will explain exactly what that means

Comment: Hi, hopefully this will suffice, thanks again.

Comment: You still aren't following the directions... What exactly happens when you try this?

Comment: Sorry, I have added my output now and what I expected to get.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Could you point out my error please and I’ll try to correct it.

Comment: If you attempt to run this code, the interpreter will provide you this information immediately. Stack overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: Now that you have posted runnable code, one further comment: `['what_type']` should probably be `x['what_type']`.